# What does ほん mean?

Tags: grammar, translation

Good evening, I was reading a manga and I'm not sure if it's ほん or if it's another expression, because something appears first that seems to be a zero, something like this:
0ほん...

[image]

Comment: That small circle is called the [_handakuten_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakuten_and_handakuten) and it changes "H" sounds to "P" sounds.  So instead of _hon_, it's _pon_.  This _pon_ is often a sound effect, but my grasp of manga conventions isn't very strong, so I'll let someone else who knows better respond with a fuller answer.

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot of the full panel? The meaning of onomatopoeia can change [depending on the situation](http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/search/?keyword=%E3%81%BD%E3%82%93&submitSearch=Search+SFX&x=).

Answer (score 2):

It's **ぽん(pon)** not **ほん(hon)**. And as far as I can tell, it's simply a onomatopoeia, aka a word that mimics the sounds "pon!"

The circle on top is called 半濁点, which means half-voiced-dots. They only exist for the ha-line of the kana's (はha, ひhi, ふhu, へhe, ほho), and turns them into ぱpa, ぴpi, ぷpu, ぺpe, ぽpo.

I will not extend my answer beyond 半濁点 here, but please look at [this](https://blog.nihongomaster.com/japanese-hiragana/) for all possible sounds Hiragana can represent. It also explains 濁音 and 半濁音.